# LinearLayout visibility not 'GONE' and also doesn't show on android 4.4.4

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout, floating-action-button

I'm using a `LinearLayout` as a "skrim" to cover a layout after a floating action button is pressed where I have it set to a color with the alpha set to .55 and it covers the entire parent. In my layout, I set the `LinearLayout` to "gone" and then in my kotlin, I pragmatically switch the `LinearLayout` between `VISIBLE` and `GONE` when the `FAB` is touched.

For some reason, the LinearLayout doesn't show on apk19 4.4.4 at all but, it is always there meaning you cannot press and of the mini fabs.  You can press the main FAB, but nothing else.  I have a `setOnClickListener` for the `LinearLayout` so I know that it's getting pressed and not the mini FAB's

here's the `LinearLayout':

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_profile_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.55"
        android:foreground="@color/profile"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

And here's the Kotlin to pragmatically change the `LinearLayout`:

```
view.main_profile_overlay.visibility = View.GONE
```

and

```
view.main_profile_overlay.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Why does the layout not go away using `GONE` and why does it not show the color and alpha?

****Edit****

Here's my full layout  Nothing I do modifies the `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileUserCoverPhotoLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@color/profile"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileUserCoverPhoto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@color/profile"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/editProfileCoverPhoto"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/profile"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_edit_image" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/editPorofileUserPhoto"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/profile"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/profileUserPhoto"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_edit_image" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profilePersonalInfoChild"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/profilePersonalInfoChild2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:paddingStart="0dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileUserPhoto"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/profile_image_border"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profilePersonalInfoChild3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:paddingStart="0dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/profileUsername"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/Username"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="28sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/profileMemberSince"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Member since September, 2018"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        tools:text="Member since September, 2018" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileAboutMeLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:labelFor="@+id/profileAboutMe"
                android:text="@string/aboutMe"
                android:textColor="@color/profile"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileAboutMe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:text="My bio"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileCityLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:labelFor="@+id/profileCity"
                android:text="@string/city"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/profile"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:text="My city"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileAgeLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:text="@string/age"
                android:textColor="@color/profile" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileAge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:text="My age"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileOccupationLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:labelFor="@+id/profileOccupation"
                android:text="@string/occupation"
                android:textColor="@color/profile"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileOccupation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:text="My occupation"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileInterestsLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:labelFor="@+id/profileInterests"
                android:text="@string/interests"
                android:textColor="@color/profile"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileInterests"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:text="My interests"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_profile_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.55"
        android:foreground="@color/profile"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_profile_open"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/profile" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_profile_close"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/profile" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_profile_edit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_edit"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_profile_photo_edit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chatter_new_photo"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="142dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="92dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_profile_search"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_groups_search"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="154dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/profileProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: may be you check your workflow is correct or wrong?

Comment: The `LinearLayout` is at the bottom of the entire layout, which is where I want it in order to cover everything except the floating action buttons.  The problem is I have two floating action buttons that are going to be above the `LinearLayout`, plus, I'm going to make the text in some of the `EditText` editable on the press of an edit button.  These `EditText`'s will be above that `LinearLayout`.  When I set the `LinearLayout` to gone, should it not be completely gone from the layout at that point?  Why is it still there and clickable?

Comment: Also, why don't the FABs appear above the layout?  on my note9 (apk27) they do appear above the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: did you used invisible property anywhere instead of Gone?

Comment: No.  `INVISIBLE` doesn't remove the object from the layout.  `GONE` is supposed to do that though.

Comment: yes..Gone is prefect.. that  why am asking by mistake did you used anywhere invisible?

Comment: No, I didn't use `INVISIBLE` anywhere.  Only `GONE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting background color rather than foreground color and make your to layout height to match parent

```
       <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/main_profile_overlay"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:alpha="0.55"
          android:background="@color/profile"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Yes, you were correct.  It was that I had the color as foreground, but it should have been background.  Also, the `LinearLayout` should be above the Floating Action Buttons, but below the content, you want to cover.  If you could update your answer to reflect putting the `LinearLayout`above the FABs for anyone searching, that would be great.

Comment: Once you update the answer, I will click the checkmark.